# Js inherit from class via prototypes

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

I need to inherit [DataView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView) object to create my own `type` and add additional methods etc. But I'm a bit confused how to do this in a right way. I tried to do like this:

```
var CFDataView = function() {
    this.offset = 0;
};

CFDataView.prototype.__proto__ = DataView.prototype;

CFDataView.prototype.readU8 = function() {
   if (this.byteLength >= this.offset+1) {
     return this.getUint8(this.offset++);
   } else {
     return null;
   }
};
```

But got an error:

> DataView.prototype.byteLength called on incompatible receiver CFDataView

From the proposals, I tried to do like this:

```
var CFDataView = function CFDataView(buffer, byteOffset, byteLength) {
            DataView.call(this, buffer, byteOffset, byteLength);
            this.offset = 0;
        };

        CFDataView.prototype = Object.create(DataView.prototype);
        CFDataView.prototype.constructor = CFDataView;
```

But receive an error:

> TypeError: Constructor DataView requires 'new'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use ES6 `class` to extend the native classes such as `DataView`. As the error messages say, you can only use the methods on real dataviews ("compatible receivers"), and to create such you need to use the `DataView` constructor (with `new` - or with `super` or `Reflect.construct`). So

```
class CFDataView {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args)
    this.offset = 0;
  }
  readU8() {
    if (this.byteLength >= this.offset+1) {
      return this.getUint8(this.offset++);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```